# Using Glide to add image to toolbar

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-glide

I'm creating an app where the user can pick a profile image from a selection of avatars. The avatar image URLs are stored in Firebase database. When the user has selected an image I would like it to show in my toolbar. So I thought something like this would work:

```
 private void setToolBar(){
    ref.child("Users").child(userID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            String profileimage = snapshot.child("OnavatarId").getValue(String.class);
            String profileusername = snapshot.child("OnUsername").getValue(String.class);
             profile_image = mtoolbar.findViewById(R.id.image);

            Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(profileimage).into(profile_image);

            setSupportActionBar(mtoolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Toolbar XML:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_app_bar"
android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary">

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have problem with `profileimage` url to image. To be sure add `.error(R.drawable.error)` to your glide request when loading photo.

Comment: get a cant resolve error when i add r.drawable.error?

Comment: it can be any `drawable` or `bitmap` from your project that shows you that there is an error.

Comment: it appears my datasnapshot is returning empty..hmmm

Comment: ok so ive got it to show.. but now its appearing fullscreen